# How to refresh correctly mutiple list with Subject in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have two list to refresh for two different event (one post, one delete). The issue is that when delete is called, It calls also the post method. So I delete someting, but the post re-post it :p

The lists to refresh are the profileUser$ and the ptofileListDistinct$

**Initialization:**

```
export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {

  userId: string = "";
  currentUser$!: Observable<User>;

  profileUser$!: Observable<ProfileUser[]>;
  profileListDistinc$!: Observable<Profile[]>;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private profileService: ProfileService,
    private reloadProfile: SearchEmitterService,
    private confirmDialogService: ConfirmDialogService
  ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.userId = id ? id : "";

    this.currentUser$ = this.userService.getUser(this.userId);

    this.profileUser$ = this.reloadProfile.reloadprofileUserBehavior$.pipe(
      switchMap(
        x => this.profileService.getProfilesForUser(this.userId)));

    this.profileListDistinc$ = this.reloadProfile.reloadProfileListDisctincBehavior$.pipe(
      switchMap(x => this.profileService.getProfilesDisctinc(this.userId)));
  }
```

**Post Method:**

```
  onAddProfileUser(profileId: string, userId: string) {
    let newProfileUser: ProfileUserCreate = {
      profileId: profileId,
      userId: userId
    }

    this.profileService.addProfileForUser(newProfileUser)
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.reloadProfile.reloadprofileUserBehavior$.next(null);
        this.reloadProfile.reloadProfileListDisctincBehavior$.next(null);
      });
  }
```

**Delete Method:**

```
onDeleteProfileUser(profileUser: ProfileUser): void {
        this.profileService.deleteProfileForUser(profileUser)
          .subscribe(x => {
            this.reloadProfile.reloadProfileListDisctincBehavior$.next(null);
            this.reloadProfile.reloadprofileUserBehavior$.next(null);
          });
      }
```

**Reload Service:**

```
export class SearchEmitterService {
  reloadProfileListDisctincBehavior$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  reloadprofileUserBehavior$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor() { }
```

Comment: What's the point of calling these two BehaviorSubjects in onDeleteProfileUser(){}             this.reloadProfile.reloadProfileListDisctincBehavior$.next(null);
this.reloadProfile.reloadprofileUserBehavior$.next(null);    ?

Comment: I do not also think you need BehaviorSubject here Subjects can be enough

Comment: The purpose is to refresh the profile list for a user when a profile is deleted. So when I delete one profile, the behavior call the backend to get again the list and load it (without the deleted profile). Same when I add a new profile, it has to retrieve the newed list with the newed profile added to it.

I use a behaviorSubject because when the page load, it load the list, so I need an initial value.

Comment: Still having this issue, any idea ?

Comment: provide  a stackblitz with relevant Angular code if you want help